# Wrong content-type received (AFNetworking bug)?

Tags: ios, mysql, json, afnetworking

I send JSON response via AFNetworking from server to my app request. Also it's one script on server (php) and one DB (MySQL).

When I make requests to different tables (within the same DB) - comes valid response (JSON), but from only one table comes "image/jpeg" (afnetworking says me that) ... although the content-type on the server is correctly configured (`header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');` in .php).

What could be the problem?
Applied to a support - said they sent the correct headers (JSON)...why then AFNetworking sees the header image/jpeg?

ADDED SCREENSHOT OF CHROME DEV TOOL (correct json here):

[image]

[image]

**But AFNetworking says:**

[image]

Comment: If you make the same request using command line tools, what do you see?

Comment: My bet is that the server sends wrong content type. AFNetworking relies on CFNetwork APIs and those are quite well tested and reliable... What happens if you try the request with developer tools in say, Google Chrome and look in the network tab?

Comment: Is any "cache" in AFNetworking? I just run app on different simulator, and get correct json header! .... and still get "image/jpeg" on my iphone ..... :-/

Comment: Have you solved this issue? I am having exactly the same problem...

Comment: It seems that the problem has arisen because of the encoding of the table on the server (mysql). Try to change it.
Remember seems to have solved the problem after changing the encoding